# Creating a nested json using two arrays in node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, express, object

I have two arrays one with field names and the other array is having a list of arrays where each array corresponds to row in table.How can i use  these two arrays to create a list of JSON Objects. Is there any in built function. I am able to acheive this using map/reduce/ for -loop but this is impacting the performance if the second array is having more rows as we have traverse through each row.

I hope the following explains the use case better. Please share the sample code if possible.

```
Arr1=[field1,field2];

Arr2=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];

Expected Output:
[
{
field1 :1 ,
field2: 2
},
{
field1 :3 ,
field2: 4
},
{
field1 :5 ,
field2: 6
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` to map the elements

```
const mapFields = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const mappedArray = arr2.map((el) => {
        const mappedArrayEl = [];
        el.forEach((value, i) => {
            if (arr1.length < (i+1)) return;
            mappedArrayEl[arr1[i]] = value;
        });
        return mappedArrayEl;
    });
    return mappedArray;
}

const Arr1 = ["field1","field2"];
const Arr2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
console.log(mapFields(Arr1, Arr2));
```